# function return value in python

Tags: python, function

I wrote the following code:

```
def addInterest(balance, rate):
    newBalance = balance * (1+rate)
    return newBalance


def test():
    amount=1000
    rate=0.05
    addInterest(amount, rate)
    print("" ,amount)

test()
```

I expected the output to be 1050, but it is still printing 1000. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't assign the return value to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning any value from `AddInterest`:

```
amount = addInterest(amount, rate)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function addInterest() returns the value 1050, but not apply the changes at amount variable, cos you didn't pass as a referenced variable (i think python doenst support referenced variables). You must to store the returned value into a new variable:

```
def addInterest(balance, rate):
    newBalance = balance * (1 + rate)
    return newBalance

def test():
    amount = 1000
    rate = 0.05
    # STORE RETURNED VALUE
    result = addInterest(amount, rate)
    # PRINT RETURNED VALUE
    print(result)

test()
```